# How do I pan the image inside a UIImageView?

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-animation

I have a `UIImageView` that is displaying an image that is wider and taller than the `UIImageView` is. I would like to pan the image within the view using an animation (so that the pan is nice and smooth).

It seems to me that I should be able to just adjust the `bounds.origin` of the `UIImageView`, and the image should move (because the image should paint inside the view with that as **its** origin, right?) but that doesn't seem to work. The `bounds.origin` changes, but the image draws in the same location.

What almost works is to change the `contentsRect` of the view's layer. But this begins as a unit square, even though the viewable area of the image is not the whole image. So I'm not sure how I would detect that the far edge of the image is being pulled into the viewable area (which I need to avoid, since it displays by stretching the edge out to infinity, which looks, well, sub-par).

My view currently has its `contentsGravity` set to `kCAGravityTopLeft` via Interface Builder, if that makes a difference (Is it causing the image to move?). No other options seemed to be any better, though.

UPDATE: to be clear, I want to move the image **inside** the view, while keeping the view in the same spot.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Brad Larson pointed me down the right road with his suggestion to put the `UIImageView` inside a `UIScrollView`.

In the end I put the `UIImageView` inside of a `UIScrollView`, and set the scrollView's `contentSize` **and** the `imageView`'s bounds to be the same size as the image in the UIImage:

```
UIImage* image = imageView.image;
imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
scrollView.contentSize = image.size;
```

Then, I can animate the scrollView's `contentOffset` to achieve a nice panning effect:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"pan" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
scrollView.contentOffset = newRect.origin;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

In my particular case, I'm panning to a random space in the image. In order to find a proper rect to pan **to** and a proper duration to get a nice constant speed, I use the following:

```
UIImage* image = imageView.image;

float xNewOrigin = [TCBRandom randomIntLessThan:image.size.width - scrollView.bounds.size.width];
float yNewOrigin = [TCBRandom randomIntLessThan:image.size.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height];

CGRect oldRect = scrollView.bounds;
CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(
    xNewOrigin,
    yNewOrigin, 
    scrollView.bounds.size.width,
    scrollView.bounds.size.height);

float xDistance = fabs(xNewOrigin - oldRect.origin.x);
float yDistance = fabs(yNewOrigin - oldRect.origin.y);
float hDistance = sqrtf(powf(xDistance, 2) + powf(yDistance, 2));
float hDistanceInPixels = hDistance;

float animationDuration = hDistanceInPixels / speedInPixelsPerSecond;
```

I'm using a `speedInPixelsPerSecond` of `10.0f`, but other applications might want to use a different value.

Answer (score 48):

I'd highly recommend enclosing your `UIImageView` in a `UIScrollView`.  Have the `UIImageView` display the full image, and set the contentSize on the `UIScrollView` to be the same as your `UIImageView's` size.  Your `window` into the image will be the size of the `UIScrollView`, and by using `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` you can pan to particular areas on the image in an animated fashion.

If you don't want scroll bars to appear, you can set the `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator` and `showsVerticalScrollIndicator`properties to `NO`.

`UIScrollView` also provides pinch-zooming functionality, which may or may not be useful to you.

Comment: But the animation in that case is so fast that you never actually see the image, just the destination.

Comment: Enclose your scrollRectToVisible:animated: method call in a UIView beginAnimations/commitAnimations block and use UIView's setAnimationDuration: at the start of that block.  This overrides the default animation duration.  You can make the scroll view pan as slowly as you want that way.

Comment: That doesn't seem to slow down the scrolling. Here's what I'm doing:

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"bay pan" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:10];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:newRect animated:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

Comment: This lead me down the right path, so I'm giving you the "Accepted" to give you the reputation, and then posting my own answer to provide the code.