# Does anyone have a good way to scroll text off to one side, like a stock ticker in a label on a nib in an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I want to scroll text starting on the right and make it smoothly move to the left and off the screen.  Does anyone have an example of something they tried that worked?  Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430942/resizable-uilabel-which-scrolls-across-the-screen) is asking something very close to what you want to do.  The answers provided there, coupled with the methods described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419710/how-do-i-pan-the-image-inside-a-uiimageview), should let you scroll text in a smoothly animated manner.