# Marquee Effect - UILabel / UITextView

Tags: ios, uilabel, uitextview, marquee

How can I add a marquee effect to an UILabel?

(If it's not possible, `UITextView` is also ok)

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add marquee to a label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118626/how-to-add-marquee-to-a-label)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to code at all, you will find running implementation with code here :

[CocoaControls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/marqueelabel)