# How would I use an NSTimer to automatically scroll text?

Tags: iphone, nstimer

I'd like to scroll text in my iPhone application, and I believe I can use NSTimer for this.  How would I use NSTimer in this case?

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you want to do.  How are you scrolling the text?

Comment: Rather than using NSTimer, have you looked at using Core Animation, like in the question [Resizable UILabel which scrolls across the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430942/resizable-uilabel-which-scrolls-across-the-screen) ?

Answer (score 0):

on the timer elapse try this

```
[myTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
```

increment the position range instead