# How to zoom in/out an UIImage object when user pinches screen?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiimage, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I would like to zoom in/out an UIImage object when the user performs the standard pinch action on my application. I'm currently using a UIImageView to display my image, if that detail helps in any way.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this, but no such luck so far.

Any clues?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Another easy way to do this is to place your `UIImageView` within a `UIScrollView`.  [As I describe here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419710/how-do-i-pan-the-image-inside-a-uiimageview/421646#421646), you need to set the scroll view's contentSize to be the same as your `UIImageView's` size.  Set your controller instance to be the delegate of the scroll view and implement the `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` and `scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:` methods to allow for pinch-zooming and image panning.  This is effectively what Ben's solution does, only in a slightly more lightweight manner, as you don't have the overhead of a full web view.

One issue you may run into is that the scaling within the scroll view comes in the form of transforms applied to the image.  This may lead to blurriness at high zoom factors.  For something that can be redrawn, you can follow my suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448285/how-do-i-reset-after-a-uiscrollview-zoom/451629#451629) to provide a crisper display after the pinch gesture is finished.  hniels' solution could be used at that point to rescale your image.

Comment: Make sure you change maximumZoomScale and/or minimumZoomScale :).

Answer (score 94):

As others described, the easiest solution is to put your UIImageView into a UIScrollView. I did this in the Interface Builder .xib file.

In viewDidLoad, set the following variables. Set your controller to be a UIScrollViewDelegate.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.frame.size;
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
}
```

You are required to implement the following method to return the imageView you want to zoom.

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imageView;
}
```

In versions prior to iOS9, you may also need to add this empty delegate method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
}
```

The [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html) does a good job of describing how to do this:

Comment: It's ok to delete scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView: now, I've tested with iOS9 Xcode7

Comment: It works for me! Without implementing `scrollViewDidEndZooming :` method.

Answer (score 47):

Shefali's solution for UIImageView works great, but it needs a little modification:

```
- (void)pinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
        || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        NSLog(@"gesture.scale = %f", gesture.scale);

        CGFloat currentScale = self.frame.size.width / self.bounds.size.width;
        CGFloat newScale = currentScale * gesture.scale;

        if (newScale < MINIMUM_SCALE) {
            newScale = MINIMUM_SCALE;
        }
        if (newScale > MAXIMUM_SCALE) {
            newScale = MAXIMUM_SCALE;
        }

        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(newScale, newScale);
        self.transform = transform;
        gesture.scale = 1;
    }
}
```

(Shefali's solution had the downside that it did not scale continuously while pinching. Furthermore, when starting a new pinch, the current image scale was reset.)

Comment: I want pan gesture enable after pinch gesture started.How to do that?

Comment: @Gajendra: In that case, I think you should use embed your components in a scroll view, which supports both out of the box

Comment: But I want functionality for both tap gesture and pinch gesture. I have also use grid (layers) on Imageview. May I know, Is it possible to use pinch gesture and tap gesture in scroll view.?

Comment: @GajendraKChauhan: A scroll view supports pinch to zoom and panning out of the box - just remember to set the minimum/maximum zoom scale, but look also at Brad Larsons answer. And if you want tap gesture as well, you can add that as a gesture.

Comment: @JRV, what delegates do i need to add to get the self.frame.size.width to be recognized?

Answer (score 22):

Below code helps to zoom UIImageView without using UIScrollView :

```
-(void)HandlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"======== Scale Applied ===========");
        if ([recognizer scale]<1.0f) {
            [recognizer setScale:1.0f];
        }
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale([recognizer scale],  [recognizer scale]);
        imgView.transform = transform;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is supreme solution :). Thx.

Answer (score 18):

Keep in mind that you're NEVER zooming in on a `UIImage`. EVER.

Instead, you're zooming in and out on the `view` that displays the `UIImage`.

In this particular case, you chould choose to create a custom `UIView` with custom drawing to display the image, a `UIImageView` which displays the image for you, or a `UIWebView` which will need some additional HTML to back it up.

In all cases, you'll need to implement `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, and the like to determine what the user is trying to do (zoom, pan, etc.).

Comment: +1 for clarification, never thought of it that way, cheers dude

Comment: @August, can u provide me any example which zoom and rotate image on touchesBegan, touchesMoved ?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution I've used before that does not require you to use the UIWebView.

```
- (UIImage *)scaleAndRotateImage(UIImage *)image
{
    int kMaxResolution = 320; // Or whatever

    CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);


    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    if (width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution) {
        CGFloat ratio = width/height;
        if (ratio > 1) {
            bounds.size.width = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio;
        }
        else {
            bounds.size.height = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio;
        }
    }

    CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
    CGFloat boundHeight;
    UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
    switch(orient) {

        case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
            transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        default:
            [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];

    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
    }
    else {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
    }

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
    UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return imageCopy;
}
```

The article can be found on Apple Support at:
http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=7276709#7276709

Comment: -1 for a jsp hosted support page. *shakes fist at dot syntax*

Comment: Can u please provide me how to call this method (on mouse move or touch)?

Answer (score 5):

Shafali and JRV's answers extended to include panning and pinch to zoom:

```
#define MINIMUM_SCALE 0.5
#define MAXIMUM_SCALE 6.0
@property CGPoint translation;


- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    static CGPoint currentTranslation;
    static CGFloat currentScale = 0;
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        currentTranslation = _translation;
        currentScale = self.view.frame.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.width;
    }
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self.view];

        _translation.x = translation.x + currentTranslation.x;
        _translation.y = translation.y + currentTranslation.y;
        CGAffineTransform transform1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(_translation.x , _translation.y);
        CGAffineTransform transform2 = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(currentScale, currentScale);
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform1, transform2);
        self.view.transform = transform;
    }
}


- (void)pinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
//        NSLog(@"gesture.scale = %f", gesture.scale);

        CGFloat currentScale = self.view.frame.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.width;
        CGFloat newScale = currentScale * gesture.scale;

        if (newScale < MINIMUM_SCALE) {
            newScale = MINIMUM_SCALE;
        }
        if (newScale > MAXIMUM_SCALE) {
            newScale = MAXIMUM_SCALE;
        }

        CGAffineTransform transform1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(_translation.x, _translation.y);
        CGAffineTransform transform2 = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(newScale, newScale);
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform1, transform2);
        self.view.transform = transform;
        gesture.scale = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: please avoid mentioning other's answer as they can remove their answer anytime.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this, if all you want is pinch zooming, is to place your image inside a `UIWebView` (write  small amount of html wrapper code, reference your image, and you're basically done). The more complcated way to do this is to use `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, and `touchesEnded` to keep track of the user's fingers, and adjust your view's transform property appropriately.

Comment: can u suggest me any example related to your answer. How can i zoom and rotate image using touchesBegan, touchesMoved methods. My question link=> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833841/how-to-handle-multiple-touch-gesture-at-a-time?noredirect=1#comment61239098_36833841

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you don't want to zoom in/out UIImage. Instead try to zoom in/out the View which contains the UIImage View Controller.

I have made a solution for this problem. Take a look at my code:

```
@IBAction func scaleImage(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.view.transform, sender.scale, sender.scale)
        sender.scale = 1
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
```

N.B.: Don't forget to hook up the PinchGestureRecognizer.