# How to implement zoom in Preview screen of iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

My colleague developer and I cannot find how to implement double-tap or pinch-zoom in the Preview screen on iOS when 'from camera' image import option is used.  We are using standard camera to take a picture.  Once the round button is clicked, the next screen displays the taken picture and two options "Retake" and "Use Photo".  I would like to allow the user to double-tap or pinch-zoom on this screen. Current default behavior does not affect picture zoom in any way.

The screen looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb9Ts.png), but in the latest iOS7 UI.

Please advise if this is possible and what specifically do I need to do to enable zoom in this screen?  Thanks.

Comment: Try put the imageView on a scrollView.

Comment: Try the following

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500027/how-to-zoom-in-out-an-uiimage-object-when-user-pinches-screen

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that q-and-a.  Somehow I did not find it earlier.  we'll try it.