# Is there a Cocoa Control or a library extending the UIImageView class with the pinch to zoom feature?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming, pinch

So, I have to implement the pinch to zoom and double tap zoom in iOS app at different location. So , I was wondering whether there already exists such a helper library , so that all that I have to do is just set the image and every thing else is handled as in the default iOS camera roll image

Comment: Possibly duplicate check at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500027/how-to-zoom-in-out-an-uiimage-object-when-user-pinches-screen

Comment: HI @Rajesh : thanks for the redirect, but I was looking for a quick readymade solution, in the link that you provide, it contains all the hard work. As such I would be using the feature several times at different places in the app, I would prefer a one line type solution. Thanks

Comment: Hi Rahul check this http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/scale-image-with-uipinchgesturerecognizer