# Photo Scroll App - Second UIScrollView is not showing a UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a little problem showing an image in my UIScrollView, I have this code to show images in a paged scroll view like the Photos app and works like a charm:

```
- (void)createView
{
    dValue = [dConfiguration objectForKey:@"Buttons"];

    int xAxis = 0;
    int iTag = 0;
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIView *uiView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height)];
    NSString *imageName = @"";
    for (NSString* sProperty in dValue)
    {
        imageName = [util getImageName:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Image"] andRetrina:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ImageRetina"]];
        CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(xAxis + ((screenRect.size.width - 320) / 2), 0, 320, screenRect.size.height);
        UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];

        [self LoadImage:tempImageView imageName:imageName];

        tempImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        tempImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        xAxis += self.view.frame.size.width;
        [uiView addSubview:tempImageView];

        iTag++;
    }
    self.pcPage.hidden = NO;
    [self.pcPage setNumberOfPages:iTag];
    self.pcPage.pageIndicatorTintColor = PAGECONTROL_TINTCOLOR;
    self.pcPage.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = PAGECONTROL_CURRENTPAGE;
    [_svScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(xAxis, 0)];
    [_svScroll addSubview:uiView];
}
```

But now I want to add the zoom functionality so I have changed my code to this and I have added an extra UIScrollView.

like they say here: [How to zoom in/out an UIImage object when user pinches screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500027/how-to-zoom-in-out-an-uiimage-object-when-user-pinches-screen):

```
- (void)createView
{
    dValue = [dConfiguration objectForKey:@"Buttons"];

    int xAxis = 0;
    int iTag = 0;
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIView *uiView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height)];
    NSString *imageName = @"";
    for (NSString* sProperty in dValue)
    {
        imageName = [util getImageName:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Image"] andRetrina:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ImageRetina"]];
        CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(xAxis + ((screenRect.size.width - 320) / 2), 0, 320, screenRect.size.height);
        UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];

        [self LoadImage:tempImageView imageName:imageName];

        tempImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        tempImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        xAxis += self.view.frame.size.width;

        UIScrollView *uiScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
        uiScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
        uiScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
        uiScrollView.delegate = self;
        [uiScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, screenRect.size.height)];

        [uiScrollView addSubview:tempImageView];
        [uiView addSubview:uiScrollView];

        iTag++;
    }
    self.pcPage.hidden = NO;
    [self.pcPage setNumberOfPages:iTag];
    self.pcPage.pageIndicatorTintColor = PAGECONTROL_TINTCOLOR;
    self.pcPage.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = PAGECONTROL_CURRENTPAGE;
    [_svScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(xAxis, 0)];
    [_svScroll addSubview:uiView];
}
```

This code is only showing the first image and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I tough at first that maybe the new UIScrollView was not in the proper position, so I changed the backround color (in random way) of the UIScrollView and I can see the 2 scroll well paged in the main scroll:

```
iColor = 50;
[uiScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:iColor/255.0 green:131.0/255.0 blue:19.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
iColor += 50;
```

Then I tough that the view UIImageView is not un the UIView and I tested it:

```
UIImageView *v1 = [[[[uiView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
UIImageView *v2 = [[[[uiView subviews] objectAtIndex:1] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];

UIScrollView *v3 = [[uiView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
UIScrollView *v4 = [[uiView subviews] objectAtIndex:1];

UIImageView *v5 = [[[[[[_svScroll subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
UIImageView *v6 = [[[[[[_svScroll subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:1] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Nothing here is null and I can even see the image with the quick view function.

If I print the values this are the results:

> Printing description of v1:
>
> UIImageView: 0x156d6b90; frame = (0 0; 320 480); opaque = NO; layer =
>   CALayer: 0x156d4810
>
> Printing description of v2:
>
> UIImageView: 0x156dc0f0; frame = (320 0; 320 480); opaque = NO; layer
>   = CALayer: 0x156bdc90
>
> Printing description of v3:
>
> UIScrollView: 0x1639a000; frame = (0 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES;
>   gestureRecognizers = NSArray: 0x1567a060; layer = CALayer: 0x156d5c90;
>   contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 480}
>
> Printing description of v4:
>
> UIScrollView: 0x15b7d800; frame = (320 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds =
>   YES; gestureRecognizers = NSArray: 0x155dae10; layer = CALayer:
>   0x155de3d0; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 480}
>
> Printing description of v5:
>
> UIImageView: 0x156d6b90; frame = (0 0; 320 480); opaque = NO; layer =
>   CALayer: 0x156d4810
>
> Printing description of v6:
>
> UIImageView: 0x156dc0f0; frame = (320 0; 320 480); opaque = NO; layer
>   = CALayer: 0x156bdc90

As you can see it looks like the frames and the content size are ok, but for some reason I can only see the first image.

I have also tested to change the image order to see if it was something in the image but the result is the same.

I have also added this code to control the zoom:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return [[scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

And this to calculate the page:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.svScroll.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.svScroll.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.pcPage.currentPage = page; 
}
```

**So at the end, the first image works perfect, I can zoom in and out, I can scroll to the next page and I can scroll to the next page even if I have zoomed in the image, but for some reason the second image is not working (or any except the first one).**

Here you have some screen shots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the same frame for the UIScrollView and for the UIImageView:

For the UIScrollView in example you have this coordinates:

(0,0)
(320,0)
(640,0)
...

But because all the UIImageView are inside the UIScrollView you have to set the coordinates to (0,0) always.

This is how the code looks now:

```
- (void)createView
{
    dValue = [dConfiguration objectForKey:@"Buttons"];

    int xAxis = 0;
    int iTag = 0;
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIView *uiView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height)];
    NSString *imageName = @"";
    for (NSString* sProperty in dValue)
    {
        imageName = [util getImageName:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Image"] andRetrina:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ImageRetina"]];
        UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, screenRect.size.height)];
        [self LoadImage:tempImageView imageName:imageName];
        tempImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        tempImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        UIScrollView *uiScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xAxis + ((screenRect.size.width - 320) / 2), 0, 320, screenRect.size.height)];
        uiScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
        uiScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.5;
        uiScrollView.delegate = self;

        [uiScrollView addSubview:tempImageView];
        [uiView addSubview:uiScrollView];

        xAxis += self.view.frame.size.width;

        iTag++;
    }
    self.pcPage.hidden = NO;
    [self.pcPage setNumberOfPages:iTag];
    self.pcPage.pageIndicatorTintColor = PAGECONTROL_TINTCOLOR;
    self.pcPage.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = PAGECONTROL_CURRENTPAGE;

    CGRect newFrame = uiView.frame;

    newFrame.size.width = xAxis;
    [uiView setFrame:newFrame];

    [_svScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(xAxis, 0)];
    [_svScroll addSubview:uiView];
}
```

Thanks to all.