# Zoom in UIImageView : View For Zooming is called but nothing happened

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a problem for zooming in `UIImageView`.

To understand, my `UIViewController` have the following structure, very simple :

I just have a collection of images. The screen displays only one image at a time, but to see other images, I can scroll left or right. (Just like the photos app from Apple). I want the zooming feature  in these images.

This is how my `UIViewController` is working :

I have a main `UIScrollView` that contains many `UIScrollView` (one per image). Basically in each of these `UIScrollView`, there is an `UIImageView`. (I didn't use `UICollectionView` to allow zoom : I just have many `UIScrollView` that contain `UIImageView`, to allow zoom in each image).

This is how it looks :

[image]

This is how I did it :

```
var counter : Int = 0
let scrollViewWidth:CGFloat = scrollView.frame.width
let scrollViewHeight:CGFloat = scrollView.frame.height

// Add images to scrollview
for object in myObjects {
    // Configure the UIImageView
    let imgView = UIImageView(image: object.image.value)
    imgView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight)
    imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imgView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    if let rotation = viewModel?.documents?[counter].rotation {
        imgView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotation)
    }

    // Configure a UIScrollView for each UIImageView to allow both zooming and paging
    let pageScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x:scrollViewWidth * CGFloat(counter), y:0, width:scrollViewWidth, height:scrollViewHeight))
    pageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    pageScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0
    pageScrollView.contentSize = imgView.bounds.size
    pageScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    pageScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    pageScrollView.addSubview(imgView)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(pageScrollView)
    counter += 1
}

// Set content size for the main UIScrollView
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat((viewModel?.documents)!.count), height:self.scrollView.frame.height)
```

Obviously I implemented the `viewForZooming` method : the method is called, the method returns the right UIImageView, but nothing happens when I pinch to zoom :

```
/// Zoom in / out for the current UIImageView
public func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    // self.scrollView : main UIScrollView
    if scrollView == self.scrollView {
        if let childScrollView = self.scrollView.subviews[currentPageIndex] as? UIScrollView {
            if let currentImageView = childScrollView.subviews[0] as? UIImageView {
                return currentImageView // the UIImageView is well returned
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

I don't understand, if anyone have an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: you need to implement `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` also.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500027/how-to-zoom-in-out-an-uiimage-object-when-user-pinches-screen

Answer (score 1):

Set delegate to every pageScrollView (not for self.scrollView). 
In the viewForZooming, return appropriate subview.
Example (pseudocode):

```
public func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    // self.scrollView : main UIScrollView
    if <scrollView ONE_OF self.pageScrollViews> {
        return self.getContentViewForPageScrollView(scrollView);
    }
}
return nil
```

[Here](https://github.com/K-Be/ScrollInScrollPagesExample) you can find example project with minimum of the layout features.

}

Comment: I needed both delegate, on `self.scrollView` and on the other child scrollViews. But I solved my problem, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Solved. In fact as I set the delegate both to my main `UIScrollView` and the other `UIScrollView`, the `viewForZooming` method didn't know what scrollView was used. Instead of testing if the scrollView used in the method was the main `UIScrollView` (`if scrollView == self.scrollView`), I have to test if the scrollView was a **child** of the main `UIScrollView`.

Like this :

```
/// Zoom in / out for the current UIImageView
public func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    // I removed the test for the main UIScrollView...
    if let childScrollView = self.scrollView.subviews[currentPageIndex] as? UIScrollView {
        if let currentImageView = childScrollView.subviews[0] as? UIImageView {
            // ...And now I test if the scrollView is the child 
            if scrollView == childScrollView { 
                return currentImageView
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Now it works !