# Proper contentSize of UIScrollView with UIImageView inside it

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm placing a UIImageView inside of a UIScrollView, basing my code off of the answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419710/how-do-i-pan-the-image-inside-a-uiimageview/421646#421646). The problem I'm having is that there is a significant amount of white space to the bottom and right, and I can't scroll to some of the image in the top and left. I figure this is due to me incorrectly setting the contentSize of the scrollView. Here's the relevant code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _imageView.image = _image;
    _imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, _imageView.image.size.width,_imageView.image.size.height);
    _scroller.contentSize = _imageView.image.size;
 }
```

The view controller I'm in has three properties, a UIScrollView (_scroller), a UIImageView (_imageView), and a UIImage (_image).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the UIImageView's `bounds` property. You want to be setting its `frame` property instead. Setting the  bounds will resize it around its center point (assuming you haven't changed the underlying `CALayer`'s `anchorPoint` property), which is causing the frame origin to end up negative, which is why you can't see the upper-left.

```
_imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _imageView.image.size.width, _imageView.image.size.height);
```

---

Alternate syntax:

```
_imageView.frame = (CGRect){CGPointZero, _imageView.image.size};
```

Comment: I thought the frame of a view that has a transform applied is undefined, and UIScrollView applies a transform to zoom in?