# Set UIImageView (inside a View) just below translucent UINavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uinavigationbar

I have a simple UIViewController which contains an UIView (main), an UIScrollView, and an UIImageView (in the scrollview)

- UIView
- - UIScrollView
- - - UIImageView

I just want to show the imageView in full screen (it contains a picture) and to set the navigation bar translucent style, but the imageView appears displaced just when navigationBar ends, not below with a translucent effect.

How I have to configure the components (UINavigationBar, UIScrollview, UIImageview?

EDITED: Removed intermediate UIView

Comment: is it compulsory to add a view on scrollview ??????

Comment: Ok, it was a mistake… I removed the intermediate UIView but I got the same result

Comment: you use any image on navigationbar ..... or set it translucent .....?

Comment: I set navigation bar translucent, and I can move the image below the navigation bar (and I can see the translucent effect), but when init the view controller, the top image appears just below bottom navigation bar, I want to make top image just below top navigation bar

Comment: you want to set that image on view .... i suggest you that set the background image not on an UIImageView separately

Comment: but in that case I would lose zooming option, is not? I need to zoom in the image too.

Comment: you want to zoom your image on UITouch Guesture ???

Comment: NO, I just want to have an UIScrollView and UIImageView inside it. UIScrollView with zoom properties.

Comment: hey buddy go here it will help you.....[Imagezoom On Scrollview][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419710/how-do-i-pan-the-image-inside-a-uiimageview/421646#421646