# How to add a Gesture Recogniser in imageview in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

i add a UIPanGestureRecognizer to my imageview then Gesture Recognizer is added but my imageview image is panned in to my view i want only image is panned inside of the imageview on in the view how it is possible?

i write a code for that on viewdidload

```
 UIPanGestureRecognizer *pangesture=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureDetected:)];
[pangesture setDelegate:self];
[self.zoomImage addGestureRecognizer:pangesture];
```

and method for that is

```
- (void)panGestureDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
UIGestureRecognizerState state = [recognizer state];

if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];
    [recognizer.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformTranslate(recognizer.view.transform, translation.x, translation.y)];
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:recognizer.view];
}
}
```

then imageView image is panned in my View but i want image Panned only inside of imageview if it possible then give me solution.
here my original imageview Size is like as[image]

and when i added UIPanGEstureRecognizer then it look like as
[image]
image are panned in View but i want to zoom it inside of imageview size please give me solution for that.

Comment: please share some image for better understanding.

Comment: for that you have to add ImageView inside your ImageView! as you can add gestures to only objects of view and UIImage in not subclass or object of UIView!

Comment: or you can put Your ImageView in specific CustomView and then add pan gesture on it!

Comment: I believe you want to look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419710/how-do-i-pan-the-image-inside-a-uiimageview#421646

Comment: Put each UIImageView in different UIView, your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

take `UIScrollView` and add `UIImageView` inside the scrollview and pangesture on scrollview ..

set delegate for scrollview and do the code

```
- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // Return the view that we want to zoom
    return self.zoomImage;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // The scroll view has zoomed, so we need to re-center the contents
    [self centerScrollViewContents];
}

- (void)centerScrollViewContents {
    CGSize boundsSize = scrollView.bounds.size;
    CGRect contentsFrame = self.zoomImage.frame;

    if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0f;
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
    }

    if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
    }

    self.zoomImage.frame = contentsFrame;
}

- (void)scrollViewDoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    // Get the location within the image view where we tapped
    CGPoint pointInView = [recognizer locationInView:imageView];

    // Get a zoom scale that's zoomed in slightly, capped at the maximum zoom scale specified by the scroll view
    CGFloat newZoomScale = scrollView.zoomScale * 1.5f;
    newZoomScale = MIN(newZoomScale, scrollView.maximumZoomScale);

    // Figure out the rect we want to zoom to, then zoom to it
    CGSize scrollViewSize = scrollView.bounds.size;

    CGFloat w = scrollViewSize.width / newZoomScale;
    CGFloat h = scrollViewSize.height / newZoomScale;
    CGFloat x = pointInView.x - (w / 2.0f);
    CGFloat y = pointInView.y - (h / 2.0f);

    CGRect rectToZoomTo = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

    [scrollView zoomToRect:rectToZoomTo animated:YES];
}

- (void)scrollViewTwoFingerTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    // Zoom out slightly, capping at the minimum zoom scale specified by the scroll view
    CGFloat newZoomScale = scrollView.zoomScale / 1.5f;
    newZoomScale = MAX(newZoomScale, scrollView.minimumZoomScale);
    [scrollView setZoomScale:newZoomScale animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIImage object's userInteractEnable is NO by default, so you can't interact with it. Try `self.zoomImage.userInteractEnable = YES`

Comment: it is enabled #mengxiangjian it is working but i want to zoom an image not in my view but only inside of my imageview.

Comment: I recommend you to put the UIImageView in a UIScrollView,then you have mot to add a pan gesture to the ImamgeView because the scroll can do that.

Comment: #mengxiangjian i add my imageview in side my scrollview but it is add only my array last image in to scrollview not all image in side the Scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Add another `UIView` under the `imageView`, make its size exactly the same as your `imageView`. Then set your `imageView` as this `UIView`'s subview by drag and drop the `imageView` on top of this `UIView` (Assuming you are using `StoryBoard` or `xib`).
After that, if you are using `StoryBoard` or `xib`, then go to Attributes Inspector, select this `UIView`, tick `Click Subviews`. If not, just set `view.clipsToBounds = YES;`