# ScrollView is missing constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview, nslayoutconstraint

Swift 5/Xcode 12.4

My app uses a `UIScrollView` to zoom its child `UIImageView` (which is filled through code). This part works but the ScrollView keeps complaining in XIB that it's missing constraints for the x/y position or width/height.

[image]

As you can see, the ScrollView has a top, leading and trailing constraint and the width is set to equal the height. From my understanding it knows its dimensions and position because of these constraints but apparently it's not enough. I do NOT want to center the ScrollView vertically and as the app has to support both iPhones and iPads, I also can't just set a fixed "bottom space to" constraint for the ScrollView.

I already tried to set the ScrollView's width to the `ChildView`'s width and center it horizontally in it but the warning still didn't go away.

I've seen suggestions to put the ScrollView's contents inside another `UIView` but in my case it's only a single image and if I embed it inside a view, then the zooming breaks.

Why is the ScrollView still missing constraints and how do I fix it (without changing the overall layout of this ViewController)?

Answer (score 1):

A `UIImageView` (without an image) has no `Intrinsic Content Size`.

If you're going to be setting its Width and Height constraints via code, but you want to get rid of the IB layout complaints, give the image view a **Placeholder**:

[image]

---

**Edit**

If you want the view(s) to be sized in IB, but you're going to change the constraints at run-time, you can either:

Connect the constraint to an `@IBOutlet` and change the `.constant` via code (more problematic to change the multiplier if needed, so probably not the way to go)...

Or...

Give the view constraints in IB but set them as Placeholders by checking "Remove at build time":

[image]

Comment: Interesting... I never touched the `Intrinsic Content Size`, in the "Size Inspector" it's still set to `Default (System Defined)`. Setting it to 320x78 really got rid of the warning, thanks! Is there a way to have the placeholder always fill the whole width of its surrounding parent, so it looks the same, no matter if you use an iPhone or an iPad in XIB?

Comment: No, I'm not changing the constraints at runtime in my code. I set them in XIB and also don't use any fixed sizes, so the layout works with both iPhones and iPads. The only thing I do at runtime is assign the image to the `UIImageView` and change the ScrollView's zoom scales. At runtime these constraints (e.g. the 1:1 aspect ratio for the ScrollView) should still be the same.

Comment: @Neph - if you're still having trouble figuring this out when using Storyboards, take a look at this sample project: https://github.com/DonMag/EmulateMapMarkers

Comment: Thanks for the example project! This question is about purely setting constraints in XIB, without any code involved (and making the VC in the XIB look like it'll look in the real app), so please look at my future reply on the other question. I tested a couple of things: If I align the ImageView's center x/y to the `Content Layout Guide`, the warning is gone, even without the placeholder setting. Not sure why that fixes it though because the error was addressing the ScrollView, not the ImageView. Does a ScrollView have to be filled completely (top to bottom, leading to trailing) to be "happy"?